# How to remove json object from ng-repeat using forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, splice

Currently I am trying to map 2 objects using a forEach method in angularJS and display them in an accordion. I'm correctly getting all the results...however I'm not really sure how to hide or splice the objects that are outside of the validation.

So in my fiddle example...I want to not show the items that are outside of the validations(ex. forth, fifth, sixth, seventh header and value)

HTML:

```
 <accordion ng-repeat="fee in fees">
      <accordion-group ng-if="fee.feeBag.length">
        <accordion-heading>
          {{fee.headingName}}
        </accordion-heading>
          <div class="feecode-height" ng-repeat="feeParameter in fee.feeBag">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-1">{{feeParameter.name}}</div>
              <div class="col-xs-4">{{feeParameter.text}}</div>
              <div class="col-xs-2" >{{feeParameter.amount}}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
```

Controller:

```
angular.forEach($scope.fees, function(value, key) {
    angular.forEach(value.feeBag, function(value2, key2) {
        angular.forEach($scope.otherFees, function(value3, key3){
        if (value.feeBag[key2].name === value3.name) {
          value.feeBag[key2].text =  value3.text;
          value.feeBag[key2].amount = value3.amount;

          return value.feeBag[key2];            
        } else {
          // remove the ones that dont belong 
          // value.feeBag.splice(key, 1);
        }
      })
    });
  });
```

JSON:

```
$scope.otherFees = [{'name': 1, 'text': 'ok', 'amount': 2}, {'name': 2, 'text': 'hello', 'amount': 3}, {'name': 3, 'text': 'cool', 'amount': 3}];

  $scope.fees = [
    { 
      'headingName': 'firstHeader',
      'feeBag': [
        {'name': 1}
      ]
    }, 
    {
      'headingName': 'secondHeader',    
      'feeBag': [
        {'name': 2}
      ]
    },
    {
      'headingName': 'thirdHeader',    
      'feeBag': [
        {'name': 3}
      ]
    },
    { 
      'headingName': 'forthHeader',
      'feeBag': [
        {'name': 4}
      ]
    }, 
    { 
      'headingName': 'fifthHeader',
      'feeBag': [
        {'name': 5}
      ]
    }, 
    { 
      'headingName': 'sixthHeader',
      'feeBag': [
        {'name': 6}
      ]
    }, 
    { 
      'headingName': 'seventhHeader',
      'feeBag': [
        {'name': 7}
      ]
    }
  ];
```

EDIT:

Everything is working fine except for 2 issues.

my accordion headers are being repeated
the additional fields in the array that contains the validated array are still being shown

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zomdar/60f7v8h4/)

Comment: I tried but still don't understand. What is the expected output?

Comment: if you look at my fsfiddle link...its there

Comment: I have. It shows actual output. What is the expected output?

Comment: oh what i want to do is......get rid of the ones that dont match up...so the expected output would be just 1, 2, 3 with the headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to splice the array object, create a temporary array and store the desired objects into it.

***Using For Loop***:

```
  $scope.temp = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.fees.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < $scope.fees[i].feeBag.length; j++) {
          for (var k = 0; k < $scope.otherFees.length; k++) {
              if ($scope.fees[i].feeBag[j].name == $scope.otherFees[k].name) {
                  $scope.fees[i].feeBag[j].text = $scope.otherFees[k].text;
                  $scope.fees[i].feeBag[j].amount = $scope.otherFees[k].amount;
                  $scope.temp.push($scope.fees[i]);
              }
          }
      }
  }
  $scope.fees = $scope.temp;
```

**Working Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/q5s1pchd/2/

***Using Angular ForEach***

```
  $scope.temp=[];
  angular.forEach($scope.fees, function(value, key) {
    angular.forEach(value.feeBag, function(value2, key2) {
        angular.forEach($scope.otherFees, function(value3, key3){
        if (value.feeBag[key2].name === value3.name) {
          value.feeBag[key2].text =  value3.text;
          value.feeBag[key2].amount = value3.amount;
           $scope.temp.push(value);          
        }
      })
    });
  });
$scope.fees=$scope.temp;
```

**Working Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/w1rnzs99/

Comment: any reason why you're using for loops instead of forEach?

Comment: Nope, You can use forEach also, but push the correct object. The problem before was when the condition for name equality fails, and then if you try to splice, it may not work properly because the spliced object from the array may contain a name present in any other particular position of the $scope.otherFees array

Comment: getting an error that says [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys.

any ideas?

Comment: Use track by $index in your ng-repeat or track by any unique id